# Joint Space Singularities

Tags: joint, jacobian

I would like to clarify my self on singularity configurations. If I am moving the robot in joint space only one joint at a time, can I come to a singular configuration? If so how?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is a robot with a serial structure:

You will always be able to move every joint of the robot in any pose.

However the singularitites still exist, and you can end up in a singular pose, but if you do not have any cartesian space contrains  (and do not even calculate inverse kinematics/inv. jacobi), then from a motion point of view these are not significant.